# Prove from definition of convergence that (-2n+5)/(3n+1) is convergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

Prove directly from the definition of convergence that $\frac{-2n+5}{3n+1}$ is convergent.

So I let $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq to N$ implies that the  $\left | \frac{-2n+5}{3n+1}-0 \right | \leq  \frac{-2n+5n}{3n} = 1 \leq \epsilon $

But, I am looking to set $N$ equal to some number, so $1 \leq \epsilon$ isn't an ideal solution! Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hint: the limit is $-\frac23$.

Comment: You're right, I should've known that. Thank you.

Comment: There is a trick: when $n$ is large, $$\frac{-2n+5}{3n+1}\approx\frac{-2n}{3n}=-\frac23.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$.  We have

$$\left|\frac{-2n+5}{3n+1}+\frac23\right|=\frac{17}{9n+3}<\epsilon\iff n>\frac19\left(\frac{17}{\epsilon}-3\right)=:\alpha$$
so for $n_0=\max(0,\lfloor\alpha\rfloor+1)$ we have for $n\ge n_0$
$$\left|\frac{-2n+5}{3n+1}+\frac23\right|<\epsilon$$
hence we proved by definition that the limit is $-\frac23$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: As Yves points out above, the limit of this sequence is $-\frac{2}{3}$. So given $\epsilon$ you want to find $N>0$ such that whenever $n>N$ we have
\begin{equation*}
  \left|\frac{-2n+5}{3n+1}-\frac{-2}{3}\right| < \epsilon.
\end{equation*}
Now,
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{-2n+5}{3n+1}-\frac{-2}{3} = \frac{17}{3(1+3n)}.
\end{equation*}
So now given $\epsilon$, can you figure out what $N$ has to be?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.  Then

$\displaystyle \left|\frac{-2n+5}{3n+1}-\big(-\frac{2}{3}\big)\right|=\left|\frac{17}{3(3n+1)}\right|=\frac{17}{3(3n+1)}<\frac{18}{9n}=\frac{2}{n}$, so

let $ N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\displaystyle N>\frac{2}{\epsilon}$.

If $n\ge N$, then $\displaystyle n>\frac{2}{\epsilon}\implies\frac{2}{n}<\epsilon\implies\left|\frac{-2n+5}{3n+1}-\big(-\frac{2}{3}\big)\right|<\epsilon$.